# Expo Development client Ios build issue?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNDateTimePicker" was not found in the UIManager.

this error shows in

```
  "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.0.0",
```

and used

```
 "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
```

Does anyone have a solution please give me

change the version because this is not work

Answer (score 1):

A few things you can try to resolve this...

1. Delete `node_modules` and then run `npm install` or `yarn` depending on which you are using.
2. Delete build cache by running `npm start` or `yarn start` followed by `-- --reset-cache`
3. Make sure you are using a compatible/stable RN version. Versions beyond `0.60.0` use autolinking for Native Modules. If you have an older version you may need to [link them manually](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/react-native/legacy/manual-linking-guide/) before running your app.
4. Also make sure to go into your iOS directory and run pod install. If you haven't done this your app will likely not build or run on iOS.

```
> cd ios
> pod install
> cd ..
> npm start
```

Ideally I'd recommend updating RN if you have less than `0.60.0` if you're able just because that is a rather old version and `>0.60.0` contains a healthy amount of updates/fixes that could make your life easier haha.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this issue for a while. But I fixed it with the steps below.

1. `npx expo install @react-native-community/datetimepicker`
2. `cd ios`
3. `npx pod-install`

Please note I am using the following versions:

- React Native version: 0.72.6
- Expo version: 49.0.15
- dateTimePicker version: 7.2.0

Now I import the package like it does in the docs:

```
import DateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";
```

For ios I need to use it like this which is not what is in the docs:

```
<DateTimePicker mode="date" value={date} />
```

where date is set by a default state in the following:

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
```

I know you are using the modal package but that is dependent on the community picker, hope this helps in your case!